# searching quote char with surround query parser in SOLR

Tags: solr, solr4

I am trying to search for two subsequent words as follow:

```
{!surround}FieldName:first w second
```

The query works great, but SOLR throws parse exception when one of the words contains quote char, i.e

```
{!surround}FieldName:first w sec"ond
```

I have tried to escape the qutoe:

```
{!surround}FieldName:first w sec\"ond
```

but it didnt help.
I tried also using the v parameter of LocalParams, but no good either.

```
{!surround v="first w sec\"ond"}FieldName
```

I am currently running Solr 4.0. 
Does anybody knows how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: 
`{!surround}FieldName:(w(first,"sec\"ond"))`