# SOLR proximity logic

Tags: solr, proximity

in query like

```
"foo bar"~4
```

You'd expect it to bring :

```
foo word1 word2 word3 bar
```

but I find out it bring me the other dircetion

```
bar word1 word2 word3 foo
```

Is this expected behavior (two ways) or I'm doing something wrong here>?

In short - does it ordered or un-ordered? and if it's unordered how can I explicitly ask for something **AFTER** something else?

Comment: The answer to my question is {!surround}  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935363/searching-quote-char-with-surround-query-parser-in-solr